# Probability of a right angled triangle with sides a+b=200 having hypotenuse ≥ 160

Tags: probability, random-variables, stochastic-analysis

**QUESTION**: A $200\, cm$ long staff breaks in two at a random point. The two parts becomes the right sides of a right angled triangle. What is the probability of the hypotenuse being at least $160\,cm$?

So, I defined the sides $X$ an $Y$;

$X :=$ break point on the interval $[0,2]$, and $Y:=2-X$. With Pythagorean Theorem, the hypotenuse $\sqrt{X^2+(2-X)^2} ≥ 160$. Am I doing something wrong here so far?

Comment: If you use 2 you should limit at 1.6

Comment: @N74 Thanks, rookie mistake, ha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up units. If you define the interval as $[0, 2]$, then you need to set the inequality $\geq 1.6$ (as pointed out by @N74's comment). Alternatively, if you keep the units in cm, then the interval is $[0, 200]$. You then have the inequality $X^2 + (200 - X)^2 \geq 160^2$ (or $X^2 + (2 - X)^2 \geq 1.6^2$). Simplify the inequality and solve for $X$ to find the interval where the hypotenuse is $\geq 160 \text{ cm}$, then divide the size of that interval by the size of the original interval to find the probability.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! Time for more coffee I feel. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a uniformly distributed random variable over $[0,200]$,
$$ \mathbb{P}[X^2+(200-X)^2 \geq 160^2]=\mathbb{P}[|X-100|\geq 20\sqrt{7}] $$
hence the wanted probability is:
$$ 1-\frac{40\sqrt{7}}{200} = \color{red}{1-\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{7}} \approx 47\%. $$